# Why xstate transition is not working for me in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, state-machine, xstate

```
//Customer State Machine
const CustomerStateMachine = createMachine(
  {
    id: "customer",

    initial: "pending",

    states: {
      pending: {
        on: {
          PASSWORD_RESET_COMPLETED: {
            target: "active",
            actions: ["activate"],
          },

          DELETE: {
            target: "delete",
            actions: ["delete"],
          },
        },
      },

      active: {
        on: {
          DEACTIVATE: {
            target: "deactive",
            actions: ["deactivate"],
          },

          DELETE: {
            target: "delete",
            actions: ["delete"],
          },
        },
      },

      deactive: {
        on: {
          ACTIVATE: {
            target: "active",
            actions: ["activate"],
          },

          DELETE: {
            target: "delete",
            actions: ["delete"],
          },
        },
      },

      delete: {
        type: "final",
      },
    },
  },
  {
    actions: {
      // action implementations

      activate: async (context, event) => {
        await updateCustomerState(context, event, cepSTATUS.CUSTOMER.ACTIVE);
        console.log("activate called....");
      },

      delete: async (context, event) => {
        await updateCustomerState(context, event, cepSTATUS.CUSTOMER.DELETE);
        console.log("delete customer called....");
      },

      deactivate: async (context, event) => {
        console.log("deactivate customer called....");
        await updateCustomerState(context, event, cepSTATUS.CUSTOMER.DEACTIVE);
        console.log("deactivate customer called....");
      },
    },
  },
);

//update customer state using this function

const updateCustomerState = (context, event, status) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //customer id validation
    if (!event.customer_id) {
      return reject("Invalid customer id");
    }

    //update customer status here

    Customer.update(
      {
        state: status,
      },
      {
        where: {
          customer_id: event.customer_id,
        },
      },
    )
      .then((cResult) => {
        if (!cResult) {
          return reject("Invalid customer");
        } else {
          return resolve(cResult);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        return reject("failed to update customer state");
      });
  });

//I have implemented this state machine for customer.

//Call Account State Machine and set account state from pending to active

const customerService = interpret(CustomerStateMachine)
  .onTransition((customerState) => {
    console.log(customerState.value);
  })
  .start();

//below line works for me

customerService.send("PASSWORD_RESET_COMPLETED", { customer_id: decodedToken.customer_id });

//but when I try below to change state of customer to deactivate customer its not working

const service = interpret(CustomerStateMachine)
  .onTransition((customerState) => {
    console.log(customerState.value);
  })
  .start();

const currentState = "active";

const nextState = CustomerStateMachine.transition(currentState, "DEACTIVATE").value;

service.send("DEACTIVATE", { customer_id: customer_id });
```

I have customer table with column state where i store customers. where state=1 means pending, state=2 means active state=3 means deactivated, state=4 means deleted and I have to manage customer state in database as per actions. I am trying to use state machine to check the allowed action in current state. DOes I am doing something wrong?
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We'll need more information to properly help you: what specifically is going wrong (what does "it's not working" mean?), and do you have a *minimal* working example of the issue? See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [Creating a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve - maybe you want the machine to start from a different state than the initial "pending" one? Not sure if that's even possible - other than using a transient state node that determines the next state based on the machine's context.

Otherwise, this should work:

```
const customerService = interpret(CustomerStateMachine)
  .onTransition((customerState) => {
    console.log(customerState.value);
  })
  .start();

customerService.send("PASSWORD_RESET_COMPLETED", { customer_id: customer_id });
customerService.send("DEACTIVATE", { customer_id: customer_id });
```

Comment: Yes please let me know how it can be achieved using transient state node?